# How to set page redirect after a certain time frame

Tags: c#, response.redirect

I am wanting to have a rotating pages in my application and I have found how to redirect to another page. My question is how can incorporate a certain time frame of when to redirect. example to clarify:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    Response.AppendHeader("PageSwitch", (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PageSwitch"]));
    Response.Redirect("test.aspx", true);
}
```

I was trying to have the page switch off a value I set in my AppSettings in web config that way it can be changed. I have this as a start. I can't turn the AppendHeader into an if statement because of void to bool problems. How can I make this to load the new page after 30 seconds or preferably after my value in AppSettings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this tutorial](http://nice-tutorials.blogspot.com/2009/12/redirection-after-some-time-delay-in.html), it looks like you want something like:

```
Response.AddHeader("REFRESH", "30;URL=test.aspx");
```

Assuming `test.aspx` is the target and you want the redirection to occur after thirty seconds.